# Remove time-wasting prompts like "data network mode will be deactivated"

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I've just upgraded a Galaxy S2 to ICS and when I now toggle data network mode by long-pressing the power button I get these time-wasting prompts like "Data network mode will be deactivated. OK/Cancel?". Any way to turn them off?

Answer (score 2):

No. However, you can use an app like [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) and then create a custom widget which when pressed will toggle a number of options like brightness, WiFi, Bluetooth, 2G/3G and of course mobile data.

This will happen without any confirmation dialog popping up.

Comment: yes, but it's usually quicker for me to use the power button and touch the ok, especially from the lock screen or another app..

Comment: You can configure Widgetsoid to show the widget within the notification dock slider as well, so that would work from almost all apps as well. If you use WidgetLocker lock screen, the widget may be placed on the lock screen itself. Other than these methods, no easy way, to my limited knowledge, of removing the prompt.